# Faster way to find an occurrence of 2-Dimensional array of keywords with frequency value

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

Do I have a faster way to count all frequency of all elements in 2-Dimensional array? Like this sample:

```
var array = [["a", "b"]["c", "d"]["b", "d"]["c", "a", "b"], ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
```

My expected result would be an array of objects contain keyword and frequency value. 
Like this,

```
result = [{ keyword: "a",
            frequency: 3
          }, {
            keyword: "b",
            frequency: 4
          }, ... ];
```

Here is my solution:

```js
function generateData (records) {
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < records; ++i) {
      data.push(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]);
  }
  // some gap to insert data
  setTimeout(function () {
  }, Math.random() * 1000);
  return data;
}

function mine (data) {
  var result = [];
  data.forEach( function (keywords) {
      for (var i = 0, len = keywords.length; i < len; ++i) {
          var pos = result.map( function (x) {
              return x.keyword;
          }).indexOf(keywords[i]);

          if (pos == -1) {
              var newKeyword = {
                  keyword: keywords[i],
                  frequency: 1
              }
              result.push(newKeyword);
          } else { 
              result[pos].frequency += 1;
          }
      }
  });
  return result;
}

var dataset = generateData(50000);

var start = performance.now();
var result = mine(dataset);
var end = performance.now();

console.log(result);
console.log("Total time: " + (end - start) + " milliseconds.");
```

Does anyone have a faster way to solve this problem?
Note: With 2-Dimensional of keywords array (around ~50,000 records).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this really is a bottleneck and squeezing speed out of the counting is worth code that's not quite as pretty as the functional solutions, you will have a hard time beating `for` loops in today's javascript engines. In my tests this is about twice as fast as using `reduce()`:

```
var array = [["a", "b"],["c", "d"],["b", "d"],["c", "a", "b"], ["a", "b", "c", "d"]];

let counts = new Map()
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
        let n = counts.get(array[i][j]) || 0
        counts.set(array[i][j], n + 1)
    }
}
```

JSperf [Benchmark here](https://jsperf.com/fororreduce)

Comment: Very interesting performance, clear code and easier to read. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.reduce()` to get the desired frequency in the form of an object:

```js
let data = [
  ["a", "b"],
  ["c", "d"],
  ["b", "d"],
  ["c", "a", "b"],
  ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
];

let result = [].concat(...data).reduce((r, c) => (r[c] = (r[c] || 0) + 1, r), {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: While this is a cool approach, it would be improved if you gave performance comparison with the OPs solution, since they said "faster" which could mean less code or it could mean less cycle time for the calculation.

Comment: That should be a lot faster, Thanks for the ideas! 
I will try to test with my datasets and find the running time for that.

Comment: This one actually faster, I tested with the snippet in my original question.

Answer (score 3):

You could simplify it to something like this using [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const input = [["a", "b"],["c", "d"],["b", "d"],["c", "a", "b"],["a", "b", "c", "d"]]

,output = input.flat().reduce((acc, a) =>
  ((acc[a] = acc[a] || {keyword: a, frequency: 0})["frequency"]++, acc)
,{})

console.log(Object.values(output))
```

If `flat` isn't [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Browser_compatibility), use `[].concat(...input).reduce()`

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce complexity by storing words in a map, then iterating on the map at the end.  This saves iterating on the result for every word

Old complexity `O(N * M * R)` array * word in each group * result
New complexity `O(N*M + R)`

Note:  `Array.prototype.concat`, I believe, has a big runtime.  For each concat, a new object is created and the existing and new values are copied into that new object and returned.  That's why the old arrays are not modified.  So values are read over and over.

```js
var array = [["a", "b"],["c", "d"],["b", "d"],["c", "a", "b"], ["a", "b", "c", "d"]];
var resultMap = {};
array.forEach(function (keywords) {
    keywords.forEach(function(word, i){
    if(resultMap[word]) {
        resultMap[word].frequency = resultMap[word].frequency + 1;
    }
    else{
        resultMap[word] = {
        keyword: word,
        frequency: 1
      };
    }
  });
});

console.log(Object.values(resultMap));
```

Comment: edited to make it actually work.  pro tip for the day: check code for errors before submission!

Comment: changed iteration to Object.values after reading adiga's answer

Answer (score 1):

Here I convert the original array to string and then count the character into another array as a result.

```js
const array = [
  ["a", "b"],
  ["c", "d"],
  ["b", "d"],
  ["c", "a", "b"],
  ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
]
let result = array.join().replace(/[ ]/g, '').split(',')
let count = {}
result.forEach(c => count[c] = (count[c] || 0) + 1)
console.log(count)
```

Comment: This is faster?

Comment: What for `replace` here? I get the very same result using only `array.join().split(",")`. Although I like your solution because it's a bit different from others, it's still the slowest one if compare to reduce and for loop. .